# Apache Axis1 compatibility with JDK11

Tags: java, axis

I don't have a lot experience with Java but I was tasked to update a tomcat web service project so it uses JDK11 instead of JRE1.8. I embedded JDK11 without changing any dependencies, but now I got this error when sending request to the service:

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: Receiver class org.apache.axis.message.RPCElement does not define or inherit an implementation of the resolved method abstract isSameNode(Lorg/w3c/dom/Node;)Z of interface org.w3c.dom.Node.
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.validation.DOMValidatorHelper.validate(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.validation.DOMValidatorHelper.validate(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.validation.ValidatorImpl.validate(Unknown Source)
    at java.xml/javax.xml.validation.Validator.validate(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.xml.validation.Jaxp13ValidatorFactory$Jaxp13Validator.validate(Jaxp13ValidatorFactory.java:68)
    at org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.interceptor.AbstractValidatingInterceptor.handleRequest(AbstractValidatingInterceptor.java:186)
    at org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.interceptor.DelegatingSmartEndpointInterceptor.handleRequest(DelegatingSmartEndpointInterceptor.java:78)
    at org.springframework.ws.server.MessageDispatcher.dispatch(MessageDispatcher.java:224)
    at org.springframework.ws.server.MessageDispatcher.receive(MessageDispatcher.java:173)
    at org.springframework.ws.transport.support.WebServiceMessageReceiverObjectSupport.handleConnection(WebServiceMessageReceiverObjectSupport.java:88)
    at org.springframework.ws.transport.http.WebServiceMessageReceiverHandlerAdapter.handle(WebServiceMessageReceiverHandlerAdapter.java:59)
    at org.springframework.ws.transport.http.MessageDispatcherServlet.doService(MessageDispatcherServlet.java:221)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:838)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:217)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:673)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

We're still using Axis1 (v1.4), and to the best of my knowledge (and my research) it is supposed to be compatible with JDK11, so I guess I'm missing something obvious here, and I don't know what. How can I fix this error?

Comment: Include a list of dependencies that you are using. Seems to be some incompatibility with W3C DOM API. For example: https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.w3c/dom/2.3.0-jaxb-1.0.6/jar

Comment: Judging by the error message, Axis1 seems to be compiled with DOM Level 1 or 2 (isSameNode method was added in Level 3) but at runtime there is Level 3 API present. Or maybe you have several versions of the same API in your classpath?